# How to get magento configurable attribute items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm trying to load the options for configurable products using jquery to make the template faster. the idea is to show the default options and let the customers choose which item they want to change. But, I couldn't find any direction about how magento modules can return something to a jQuery function. Any ideas?

```
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx for all the help. it may help me on the next steps. I found the answer to start the solution in here.
http://www.atwix.com/magento/ajax-requests-in-magento/

with this, I can load the configurable product with the default options and then, show just what the customer wants to change.

Answer (score 2):

All of the item's options are, in native magento, contained in the spConfig javascript object, it's defined on catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

With that object you can get all options, for attributes use, spConfig.config.attributes, for a list of attribute ids and codes, use  spConfig.config.attributes["attrId"].options you will get the options for the attribute, as well as the products pertaining to that option, output spConfig.config.attributes["attrId"].options to the console and you will get a few objects that each contain something like:

```
id
    "1221"

label
    "Gris"

oldPrice
    "650"

price
    "650"

products
    ["1137"]
```

ID is the attribute id Label is the Option label, oldPrice and price are used for super attributes, oldPrice is the defalt price and price is the price of the attribute, products is a list of products that have this attribute.

To select the first option of each attribute, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    for(var i=spConfig.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
      spConfig.settings[i].selectedIndex = 1;
    }
    spConfig.reloadPrice();
</script>
```

Comment: in fact, that's the file I want to change. I just want to load those lines (before the javascript) if the customer wants to choose another option. but, I don't know which and where I do need to create a php file to get those lines and load the options without refresh the whole page.